# How to build a angular project with yeoman and grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

Sorry if this is a very basic question but I've googled and can't find any answear on this question.

So I've generated a angular project with "yo angular". My project is completed and now I wishes to build it so everything is minified and placed in a "dest" folder. How do I do this? I run "grunt server". Is this correct if you wish to build a project?

I get this:
[image]

"Nothing to compile". I thought everything was prepared when I uses yeoman? Should I modify gruntfile.js somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No grunt server is to run a test version on server.

You have to run "grunt"

In fact you have a GruntFile.js in your project. 
This file is your build a little bit like maven.

In this gruntFile you'll see differents micro tasks like ngmin, conca, and something more. I suggest you to understand and study all these tasks really.

Then you have this :

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
```

So here we're saying ok the default task, the default command : `grunt` will run these others tasks : jshint (code quality parser), test (jasmine and angular scenario via Karma runner) then build !

Hope it helps